# Extract a dict cell and transform. Expand a dict cell into multiple rows

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a table with a dataset something like the following. Its 10 cols and 30+ rows.
The order of the records in the 'names' dictionary cell is important.  There can be more than 1 of each Title.

```
    data =[
            ['4/18/2005',   [{'grantor': 'Company1'}, {'grantee': 'Company2'}]],
            ['3/29/2005',   [{'grantor': 'Company3'}, {'grantor': 'Company1'}, {'grantor': 'Company4'}, {'grantee': 'Company5'}, {'grantee': 'Company2'}]],
            ['3/29/2005',   [{'grantor': 'Company2'}, {'grantor': 'Company9'}, {'grantor': 'Apple'}, {'grantee': 'CompnayX'}, {'grantee': 'CompanyY'}, {'grantee': 'CompanyR'}]]
        ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['fdate', 'names'])
```

I would like to do the 2 following tasks:

1. Process a single row.
   I would like to read the Names cell for a selected row, and convert it into something like this (row 1)

```
    data = [
            [{'Title': 'grantor', 'Company': 'Company1'}],
            [{'Title': 'grantee', 'Company': 'Company2'}]
           ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

2. Expand the entire data set

```
    data = [
            [{'fdate': '4/18/2005', 'pos':'1', 'Title': 'grantor', 'Company': 'Company1'}],
            [{'fdate': '4/18/2005', 'pos':'2', 'Title': 'grantee', 'Company': 'Company2'}],
            [{'fdate': '3/29/2005', 'pos':'1', 'Title': 'grantor', 'Company': 'Company3'}], 
            [{'fdate': '3/29/2005', 'pos':'2', 'Title': 'grantor', 'Company': 'Company1'}], 
            [{'fdate': '3/29/2005', 'pos':'3', 'Title': 'grantor', 'Company': 'Company4'}], 
            [{'fdate': '3/29/2005', 'pos':'4', 'Title': 'grantor', 'Company': 'Company5'}], 
            [{'fdate': '3/29/2005', 'pos':'5', 'Title': 'grantee', 'Company': 'Company2'}]
        ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: For (1) You wrote CompanyX and Company2, do you mean Company1 and Company2 since that's what it says in the first code block? You want to manipulate the data so it consists of that information for every row as the first task?

For the second task, how is the field pos being determined?

Comment: position is the order in the list.  I may have made a couple of typos in building the example, I will review and correct. for consistency and clarity.

Comment: My bad for updating multiple times. I think I should have what you wanted now. I misread the entries in your second task as three dictionaries rather than just one dictionary. Note that dictionary does not have order which is why the KV pairs in my image are not the same as the last expanded set you have.

Comment: I realized after I posted that a dict format might have been a problem, given that it can't have duplicate keys  I could change the format of  'names'  to  [    [  [xx][yy]  ]  [  [aa][b]  ] ....  ] if that would help.

Comment: No worries, I was able to reproduce the python data object you had in that last code block already. Do you mean you need it in another format for it to work? I think the duplicates are alright because we have multiple dictionaries at the moment, unless this isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at a solution:

I have labelled the parts where Task 1 is complete

```
import pprint
import pandas as pd

#Task 1
def process_row(datum, i):
    ret = []
    new_dict = {}  
    information = datum[i][1]
    for info in information:
        for (key, value) in info.items():
            new_dict['Title'] = key
            new_dict['Company'] = value
        ret.append([new_dict.copy()])
        new_dict.clear()
    return ret

#Need to create two dicts for Task 2
def process_date(datum, i):
    return {'fdate': datum[i][0]}


pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
data =[
            ['4/18/2005',   [{'grantor': 'Company1'}, {'grantee': 'Company2'}]],
            ['3/29/2005',   [{'grantor': 'Company3'}, {'grantor': 'Company1'}, {'grantor': 'Company4'}, {'grantee': 'Company5'}, {'grantee': 'Company2'}]],
            ['3/29/2005',   [{'grantor': 'Company2'}, {'grantor': 'Company9'}, {'grantor': 'Apple'}, {'grantee': 'CompnayX'}, {'grantee': 'CompanyY'}, {'grantee': 'CompanyR'}]]
        ]


#This line prints the result for Task 1.
#You should iterate if you need the function to apply to other rows.
print(process_row(data, 0))
#print(process_date(data, 0))

new_data = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    temp = process_row(data, i)
    
    for index, element in enumerate(temp):
        new_dict ={}
        new_dict.update(process_date(data, i))
        new_dict.update({'pos': index+1})
        for kv in element:
            new_dict.update(kv)
        new_data.append([new_dict])


pp=pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
pp.pprint(new_data)
```

Here is a picture of the output

The first line is the output for Task 1. The rest of the output is for Task 2, note that the it includes the third element in the original data as well.

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyFBS.jpg

Comment: Works great. but had to make a minor tweak.   new_data.append(new_dict), so that pandas would read it in.

Comment: Glad I could help.